# Programed textfile&Labels with CoreData -Swift3

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I'm using CoreData and I have an issue.

So, I'm using scroll view and in the following code it adds a label and a textfield every time the user presses the "add" button. And I need to save this to CoreData(yes it needs to be CoreData). But how can I do this? I went through CoreData relationships but couldn't understand and hoping for help.
Thank you vary much :)

```
var count = 0


@IBAction func add(_ sender: Any) {
        count += 1
        let myPoint = count * 100

        if count >= 1 {
            let myAlartController = UIAlertController(title: "Add Item", message: "Please add title and context", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            myAlartController.addTextField(configurationHandler: ({(firstText: UITextField!) -> Void in firstText.placeholder = "Please add title"}))

            myAlartController.addTextField(configurationHandler: ({(secondText: UITextField!) -> Void in secondText.placeholder = "Please add context"}))


            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                //When the bottum is pressed
                let myCGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 105, height: 30)

                //Label
                let myLabel = UILabel(frame: myCGRect)
                myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                let labelOfAlert = myAlartController.textFields?[0]
                myLabel.text = labelOfAlert?.text

                myLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                myLabel.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 60, y: (565 + myPoint))


                //textFiled
                let myTextField = UITextField(frame: myCGRect)
                myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                let textOfAlert = myAlartController.textFields?[1]
                myTextField.text = textOfAlert?.text
                myTextField.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 135, y: (565 + myPoint))

                self.labelTopConstrain.constant = (CGFloat(900 + myPoint))
                self.labelBottomConstrain.constant = 20
                self.myScroll.layoutIfNeeded()


                myLabel.tag = self.count
                myTextField.tag = self.count

                self.myScroll.addSubview(myLabel)
                self.myScroll.addSubview(myTextField)


                let testSave = Test(context: myContext)

                testSave.label = myLabel.text
                testSave.textField = myTextField.text

                (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)

            myAlartController.addAction(okButton)
            myAlartController.addAction(cancelAction)

            present(myAlartController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }/*if*/


    }/**/
```

Comment: You don't seem to have any Core Data code at all. Are you asking for an introduction to how to use Core Data, or are you already using it somewhere else in the app?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally asked the question without finishing it